# Symfony2 @Assert\Valid: traverse Vs deep

Tags: php, validation, symfony

I have a simple form that takes a very long time :

```
$builder->add('manufacturer', 'entity', array(
    'class' => 'XBundle\Entity\Manufacturer',
    ....

))
->add('type','entity', array(
  'class'    => 'XBundle\Entity\Entity\Type',


))
->add('size','entity', array(
  'class'    => 'XBundle\Entity\Size',


))
->add('serial', 'text', array(

    'required'=>true,
  ))
;
```

After installing `xhproof` and investigating the problem I found out that the **validation** is taking a big amount of time.

```
/**
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Ttm\HardwareBundle\Entity\Manufacturer", inversedBy="models")
* @Assert\Valid() <--- this line is the problem
*/
private $manufacturer;
```

Symfony2's documentation about valid annotation is not very clear:

> **`traverse`**
>
> type: `boolean` default: `true`
>
> If this constraint is applied to a property that holds an array of
>   objects, then each object in that array will be validated only if this
>   option is set to true.
>
> **`deep`**
>
> type: `boolean` default: `false`
>
> If this constraint is applied to a property that holds an array of
>   objects, then each object in that array will be validated recursively
>   if this option is set to true.

Source: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Valid.html

My question is, What's the difference between the two options and which values guarantee to me a better performance ?

Comment: It seems that `traverse` only validate the first levels but `deep` scan the first and the sub- levels of the array.

Comment: I thought that too , but `traverse=false` and `deep=true` seems to be better in performance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://api.symfony.com/2.4/Symfony/Component/Validator/ExecutionContextInterface.html

if you leave it default, by using `traverse` [link](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Valid.html#traverse), it will cover all objects inside the nested array, ignoring any arrays of objects that it sees inside this parent object, i.e. will skip validation on them.  It also has to look for, and cover anything that is instance of `\Traversable`

using `deep` [link](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Valid.html#deep) validates into these objects looking for a nested collection. It might even skip validation on those that dont meet that criteria,  like **kind of a filter** so be careful with that.

Otherwise, if your seeing a difference in performance either the `traverse` may be poorly programmed out or having to look for instances of Traversable is hard hitting.

If your not needing traversable, for your case you might consider using only `deep` since its faster, but make sure your results arent clipped.